# Why $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim N(0,n)$ when $X \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

I'm trying to understand part of a solution of a hypothesis testing problem. We have $X_1,..., X_n$ independent random observations over a random variable X. We also have two hypothesises :

- $H_0: X \sim N(0,1)$
- $H_1: X \sim N(1,1)$

In the solution there's a statement that:

when $H_0$ is true, $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim N(0,n)$,

and  when $H_1$ is true, $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \sim N(n,n)$.

**My question is**: Is that true, and if it is how and why it is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true.

Suppose that $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are identically and independently distributed $N(a,b)$ random variables. Then
$$
\operatorname E[X_1+\ldots+X_n]=\operatorname EX_1+\ldots+\operatorname EX_n=na
$$
using the linearity of the expected value and
$$
\operatorname{Var}[X_1+\ldots+X_n]=\operatorname{Var}X_1+\ldots+\operatorname{Var}X_n=nb
$$
using the independence. So now we have the expected value and the variance of the sum. However, we still need to show that the distribution is normal. This is done [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables) using several different methods.

Answer (score 1):

If $X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, then the MGF of $X$ is given by
\begin{equation*}
M_{X}(t)=e^{t\mu + \frac{1}{2}t^2\sigma^2}.
\end{equation*}
If $X_{i}$ having the MGF $M_{X_{i}}(t), i=1,2,\cdots,n$ are independent random variables, then the MGF of the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ is
\begin{equation*}
M_{\sum_{X_{i}}}(t)=M_{X_{1}}(t)\times M_{X_{2}}(t)\times\cdots M_{X_{n}}(t)
\end{equation*} 
Under $H_{0}$, since $X_{i}\sim N(0,1)$, we have,
\begin{equation*}
M_{\sum_{X_{i}}}(t)=\underbrace{ e^{ \frac{1}{2}t^2}\times e^{ \frac{1}{2}t^2}\times \cdots e^{ \frac{1}{2}t^2}}_{n\;factors}= e^{ \frac{1}{2}t^2 n}
\end{equation*}
which is the MGF of $N(0,n)$. In other words, the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$ is $N(0,n)$. Similarly, it can be shown that,  $H_{1}: \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}\sim N(n,n)$.